# Cleanest way to use a smartphone as a conventional linux workstation

Tags: distribution-choice, hardware

I have a GT-S5830 Samsung smartphone with Android 2.xxx, that I am not using as a phone.

It would be nice if the device could be used as a wifi repeater. Unfortunately, this is [impossible or not easily achievable](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12616/can-we-use-an-android-phone-as-a-wi-fi-repeater).

Sadly, the device is not listed among the [CyanogenMod supported devices](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices#searchable=%22gt-s5%22;).

[Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117368) it is explained that complete replacement of the Android for Ubuntu is impossible, and there exists some app, that installs a limited version of Ubuntu to run besides the Android, at the same time.

Unfortunately the internal RAM appers to be quite limited:

> Card slot 2 GB included Internal
>   RAM 278 MB

I need the CPU and the wifi radio. If the camera works and is accessible from OpenCV, it would be a bonus.

Can I flash a generic Linux system on this phone - with the abovementioned drivers and optionally a standard repository?

Comment: If you are doing this as a hobbyist adventure, rock on. If you are looking for the functions and **much** less hassle, find a cast-off notebook pc and pretend it is just a very big phone.

Comment: @msw, this is a hobby project. My next choice would be a 30BGN wireless router. However, I would LOVE to attach keyboard and open up a terminal on the device!

Comment: WiFi-Repeating is AFAIK called "tethering" on Android - why is this not possible on your phone? I even saw reverse-tethering solutions via USB for rooted phones...

Answer (score 5):

You can still install Android 4.2 on your device, which will solve your original problem. Here is the [xda-developer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2011671) forum.

Or if you want to flash something like debian and want to get benifit by apt-get, you can install `Lil' Debi: Debian Installer`by guardianproject. Here is [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.guardianproject.lildebi) Link

Comment: It turned out that both the current android on my phone, and my Fedora 19 laptop, **have easy gui options to work as an AP**. However, **the antenna cannot be shared**, so currently I am experimenting with tethering them together. All this to save 30BGN for a two-antenna router. Lil Debi looks great, but I think I'll be too lazy to try it for now. Until the next challenge.

Comment: Asked about the single antenna thing: [Can a device with a single wireless antenna work as a repeater?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/83957/can-a-device-with-a-single-wireless-antenna-work-as-a-repeater)